# Appeon PowerBuilder2017 R2 Configuration

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder.net, powerbuilder-conversion

Every time I try to configure appeon PowerServer it keeps on saying "Failed to connect to PowerServer 'Local PowerServer'! Please verify that the settings are correct. Does anyone here know how to fix these errors? I have try searching it still no luck. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to access http://localhost/ and see if you can get to the IIS welcome page; If you can get to the IIS welcome page, please try to access http://localhost/AEM and see what you will get.

You can report any PB bugs to the Appeon Standard Support portal at https://www.appeon.com/standardsupport/search. Bugs reported there will be responded with higher priority. And it’s now a free resource for all customers (purchased or not), so you may take advantage of it.

Regards,
Appeon Support

Comment: I have found out that Symantec is blocking my power server. I tried installing power builder 2017 r2 in test pc that didn't have Symantec and everything is running smoothly. Thank you so much for accommodating my concern. Another question, Is it possible to deploy a mobile application using mssql server database? Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely yes, I just deployed a PB2017 R2 application using Native SQL Server connection today. Tip: AEM uses TCP/IP don't make the same mistake I did and forget to enable TCP/IP and turn off dynamic port (if using SQLEXPRESS) MSS is the DBMS code for Microsoft SQL Server on AEM it's different than in PowerBuilder which uses SYC or something like that.

Comment: Also see Appeon dot com, and sign up. They have a Q & A section and are have great community. Outstanding company & management.